# javascript conflicts UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, javascript, updatepanel

I'm using a ReportViewer control which often runs into problems with the javascript associated with UpdatePanels in ASP.NET.  I've created a second page which is very simple, no Update Panels.  What's the best way to link the two pages?  An iframe sounds bad.  However, having to run a report, then be returned a link to the results also sounds bad.  Sending the user to the simple display won't work in this case.  Any suggestions, am I seeing things wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is rewrite the page that uses an update panel such that it uses straight javascript web method calls.  This would remove the need for the reportviewer control to be on a seperate page because you would no longer need an update panel.

Comment: That would certainly obviate the need to answer the question :)  However, its not an option.